# FasterXML ObjectNode filtering

Tags: java, fasterxml

I'm trying to filter all the elements in an ObjectNode and return a list of them.

Let's say I have

```
{
    custom_1: "a",
    custom_2: "b",
    another: "3",
    values: [
        custom_34: "c",
        custom_45: "d"
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to do:

```
List<String> valuesForCustom = this.node.get("custom*");
```

as an output I want to get a list with 4 elements or a map with  with all the 4 elements.

I can create a Helper to do that for me iterating over all the elements but I don't want to reinvent the wheel and maybe jackson already implemented such functionality in its own helper.

Any help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Given your input, what do you want in List<String> valuesForCustom = this.node.get("custom*");?

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: i don''t think this is possible, you can create a pojo mapped to json and can extract all the custom values